# Can anybody explain to me why this jquery function does not work?

Tags: jquery, element

I made a simple code example to narrow down my issue.

If I have this code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dosomething=function(the_selector){
        $('.content', the_selector).each(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        });
    }
    dosomething('.flickr_badge_image');
});
```

it does not work but if i change it to

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dosomething=function(the_selector){
        $(the_selector).each(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        });
    }
    dosomething('.flickr_badge_image');
});
```

It works

So why can i not combine 2 classes ('.content', the_selector) into one call? I used to be able to do this in jQuery. But somehow that stopped working?

```
$('.content',the_selector).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Of course i can call dosomething('.content,.flickr_badge_image');

But i want to understand why it does not work the way i am doing things now.

Why does it not work?  What am i missing here?

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Can you share the markup involved, such that others could try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: We need to see an appropriate example of markup.

Comment: *What am I missing* - the documentation? :)  https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context   `jQuery(selector, context)` - so `$('.content', the_selector)` is the same as `$(the_selector).find('.content')` - ie `.content` needs to be a *child* of `the_selector`.  Without your HTML it hard to tell if you meant for the_selector to be a child of .content or if you wanted both.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.content', the_selector)` will look for `.content` *below* the nodes that match `the_selector`, while you seem to want to *extend* `the_selector` with `.content`.

In that case you have several options, including:

- use jQuery: `$('.content').add(the_selector)`
- build a new selector: `$(['.content', the_selector].join())`